Cost of creating Spl-Token is higher when I use my own rust code than using generator tools
We have been trying to creating SPL Token and found that if I want to create using Pink Sale the cost is 1 Sol, if we use CoinFactory its ~0.11912 SOL and using CoinTool is about ~0.02116 SOL.
When we tried creating ourselves by writing rust code it comes upto ~0.98121 SOL. May I know why the difference between them. I thought if we can deploy ourselves it should be cheaper.
Note* for creating my own using rust, spl token is creating using the CLI commands but executed using rust and for setting the metadata, I am using metaplex and for finally the mint.

Usually, the cost for creating the token consists of rent (https://solana.com/docs/core/fees#rent) needed to be deposited to create Solana accounts. On removing accounts from Solana blockchain the rent can be withdrawn. Creation of SPL token consists of a need for several Solana accounts (mint, metadata...)
When you scroll through the https://developers.metaplex.com/token-metadata you can check the internal Solana account structure needed for the creation of the token based on the Metaplex standard. There are other standards for creating the tokens and each of them utilizes a different number of accounts and different structure of their linking.
I do not know either the Pink Sale or CoinFactory. Still, it's good to understand that different tokens can be created with a different underlying structure. Only then there could be added some fees on top of that Solana accounts structure base fee.
(probably adding some more details to your script could help to enhance the answer)

Thanks @chalda, let me check the different types of token standards and try again on the devnet.
